# Short-term mobile plans for Japan with voice calling

Tags: japan, cellphones

I'm going to visit Japan for an extended period of time soon. The visit is long enough that I would want to have a local phone number, but short enough that I won't be considered a resident and get a residence card (the length of my visit falls just a little bit under 90 days).

I've Googled a bit in both English and Japanese, as well as looked at [this](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/73172/are-short-term-visitors-in-japan-allowed-to-buy-voice-enabled-sim-cards) question, but didn't find a prepaid SIM (or similar) plan that has both voice calling and a period of validity long enough that it wouldn't be tedious to get a new card, like, every two weeks. The [SoftBank rental SIM](https://www.softbank-rental.jp/rental_japan/sim_card.php) comes close, but it is a bit pricey (110 yen/day).

I am actually on Project Fi and have free global data roaming, so I don't need a data-only plan at all. I also don't really expect to use my Japanese number all that often; maybe just for an occasional phone call or text message. That being said, I do want to have a Japanese number handy, because I expect to need it from time to time. So, is this SoftBank rental thing my only choice, or are there some better choices out there?

Comment: You might review this article: https://toomanyadapters.com/buying-sim-card-japan/ on toomanyadapters.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering my own question after a bit more digging:

[Mobal](https://www.mobal.com/japan-sim-card/) seems to provide a good plan at 1000 yen/month (voice & SMS only, as I have no need for data).

Answer (score 1):

You may want to just get a Line.app account and/or VOIP number such as through Skype or other service that’ll give you a local number.

I found in Japan that everyone preferred Line to communicate and no one ever called me on voice except for official business.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea, too, except I've already paid Mobal... Will try that next time (if there indeed is a next time).